# undefined rspec method, maybe require incorrectly?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

On my test.rb file

```
class Test
  def sum(a, b)
    a + b
  end
end
```

On my setup.rb file

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
require_relative 'test'

test = Test.new

result = test.sum 1, 2

expected = 3
expect(result).to eql(expected)
```

When I run "ruby setup.rb" on terminal, it gives me

```
setup.rb:12:in `<main>': undefined method `expect' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

i tried requiring 'rspec', which also gave me the same error. Am I requiring my lib correctly?

Comment: in ROR specs all expectations should be in `it` blocks. Not sure it is your case but you can try: add `describe Test` block and `it` block. I mean "require ... \n describe Test do \n it 'works' do \n CODE GOES HERE \n end \n end". Sorry comments do not allow to format code pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rspec doesn't pollute the global namespace just by virtue of being required.

If you include `RSpec::Matchers` then you should be able to call `expect`.

Although it is possible to use bits of rspec on their own like this, if you're just starting out with rspec it's probably not what you want. You probably want to require all of rspec and create actual specs ie

```
RSpec.describe Test do
  it "should ..."
    expect(Test.new.sum(1,2)).to eq(3)
  end 
end
```

There are plenty of getting started with rspec tutorials out there that should get you started. The [rspec-core readme](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/frames) has an example which is pretty much exactly what you're doing